# How can I go to a view by clicking on a Button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If the user clicks on `connexionBtnView`  I want to redirect them to an `AdminView` or `UserView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConnexionView: View {
    
    @State var loginId: String  = ""
    @State var pwd: String  = ""
    @StateObject private var keyboardHander = KeyBoardHandler()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Image("background")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack (spacing: 15){
                    Spacer()
                    logoView
                    Spacer()
                    titleView
                    loginIdView
                    loginPwdView
                    connexionBtnView 
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink {
                        LostPwdView()
                    } label: {
                        lostPwd
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .padding(.bottom,keyboardHander.keyboardHeight)
                    .animation(.default)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: if you have created a separate XIB and a custom class for the view... you can define the object of the class ... where ever you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavigationLink` has the `isActive` parameter. You can pass it in the init of `NavigationLink` and when this state variable has the `true` value you will redirect to another view. Details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink).

```
struct ConnexionView: View {
    
    @State var isActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(isActive: $isActive) {
                    LostPwdView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Some Label")
                }
                Button("Tap me!") {
                    isActive = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LostPwdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is having a `@State` variable that would trigger the navigation:

```
.fullScreenCover(
    isPresented: $viewShown
) {
    print("View dismissed")
} content: {
    NextView()
}
```

Where `NextView()` is the View you want to show and the `viewShown` is your State variable, below a full example:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    
    @State var isNextPageOpen = false
    
    var body: some View {
         Button("Tap Here To Navigate") {
             isNextPageOpen = true
         }
         .fullScreenCover(
             isPresented: $isNextPageOpen
         ) {
             print("View dismissed")
         } content: {
             NextView()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: .navigate , does not work on swift 5 Or maybe I forgot something, the code does not compile

Comment: @liams62217 sorry! I've updated the code to reflect swift 5, thank you!